# Product of all elements in Boost library

Tags: c++, boost

Is there an analogue of the Matlab Prod function in the Boost library? I need to calculate the product of all elements of a vector in an efficient way.

Comment: how do you define efficiency? how many elements does your vector contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) does exactly this.

```
std::vector<int> a{1,2,3,4,5};

auto product = std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 1, std::multiplies<int>());

std::cout << product; << // 120
```

Comment: Thanks. This one is in <numeric>. Can one include it from Boost?

Comment: @user44406 Its part of the standard library, so as long as you're using a standards compliant compiler you should be able to include the numeric header.

Comment: @user44406 If you need to have it in boost, it looks like they have the same functionality available. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/iteration/functions/accumulate.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll include it directly.